# Only part of a PDF is converting

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have a PDF I am trying to extract the text from.
To do this, I have tried to get the contents into a Google Doc.

The PDF has 1180 pages (3MB) but only the first 77 pages are being converted to text.
I have tried `Drive.Files.insert` and `Drive.Files.copy`, but get the same result.
I also tried to convert the PDF using MS Word and referencing that file (2.5MB) - with the same result.

I cannot see anything in either the PDF or Word that would indicate an "end of file" that would stop the rest of the document converting.  There are no error messages - just 6.5% of what I need.  I can only assume it was originally smaller PDF's that were merged.

Is there something else I should be looking at?  Has anyone encountered this before?
I can manipulate the *PDFtext* string to get the data I need, but can't convert more than the first 77 pages.
This is what I am using to get the text string I require.

```
function txtPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var mycell = sht.getRange('B1');
  var myPdfID = mycell.getValue().toString();
  var PDFblob = DriveApp.getFileById(myPdfID).getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: PDFblob.getName(),
    // mimeType: PDFblob.getContentType()
  };
  // var tmpfile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, PDFblob, {ocr: true, ocrLanguage: "en"});
  var tmpfile = Drive.Files.copy(resource, myPdfID, {convert: true, ocr: true, ocrLanguage: "en"});
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(tmpfile.id);
  // var doc = Drive.Files.copy({}, 'WordFileID', {'convert': true});
  // var doc = DocumentApp.openById('WordFileID');
  var PDFtext = doc.getBody().getText();
  // Drive.Files.remove(doc.getId());  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I fell foul of the Google Drive limits.

Documents can be up to 50MB - which was not an issue.
There is however a limit of 1.02 million characters.  The 1180 pages exceeded this, so I guess I was lucky to get anything returned at all.

[Maximum file sizes on Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en)

Comment: How many characters has your Document? You can check it on Tools > Word Count.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), the pdf to docs conversion is limited to files of 2MB or less. To convert larger files properly look for other alternatives outside of Google.